# How to properly say "bail on somebody" in German?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

I think the question in the title is clear, so let me get to some example sentences:

1. > Me and my friends had plans to go out last night. A couple of them bailed at the last second.
2. > We agreed on a plan. You can't bail out now!

I see that a literal translation of "bail from a falling plane" is "abspringen", which seems to be also used in figurative contexts as well. Would the following be a good translation:

1. > Ich und meine Freunde hatten Pläne, auszugehen. Ein paar von ihnen sind gleich davor abgesprungen.
2. > Wir hatten einen Plan. Du kannst jetzt nicht davon abspringen!

For those unfamiliar with the English phrase, to "bail/bail on somebody" means to have plans with somebody, but decide not to come at the last second.

Comment: Apart from what you are asking: "Ein paar von ihnen sind gleich davor abgesprungen." sounds weird. It should be "Ein paar von ihnen sind **kurz davor noch** abgesprungen."

Comment: Leider wird kein Beispielsatz mit "bail on somebody" gezeigt.

Answer (score 10):

While *abspringen* is very good, you might also say *einen Rückzieher machen*.
I'm not sure this would work for your first example, but for the second one *Wir hatten einen Plan. Du kannst jetzt keinen Rückzieher machen!* sounds good.

Answer (score 7):

Another idiomatic way to express this is "jemanden im Stich lassen". It certainly fits for the second example.

"Wir hatten einen Plan, du kannst mich doch jetzt nicht im Stich lassen".

It may be a little too harsh if your friends just cancel at the last second, but you can still say it just not too seriously.

"Eigentlich wollte ich mich mit meinen Freunden treffen, aber jetzt haben sie mich im Stich gelassen."

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed use *abspringen*.

According to the [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/abspringen), it's the 2nd, figurative meaning:

> unvermittelt etw. aufgeben, von etw. abgehen (um etw. Neues zu beginnen)

The [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abspringen) calls it colloquial:

> von etwas Abstand nehmen, sich von etwas unvermittelt zurückziehen; zurücktreten; sich von etwas lösen

So in principle, your translations are correct. I would still change them a bit.

**1. Example**

> Me and my friends had plans to go out last night. A couple of them bailed at the last second.
>
> Ich und meine Freunde hatten Plaene, auszugehen. Ein paar von ihnen sind gleich davor abgesprungen.

You can translate it more literally as

> Ein paar von ihnen sind in der letzten Sekunde abgesprungen.

or even

> Ein paar von ihnen sind in letzter Sekunde abgesprungen.

It's a closer to the original and idiomatic.

**2. Example**

> We agreed on a plan. You can't bail out now!
>
> Wir hatten einen Plan. Du kannst jetzt nicht davon abspringen!

I would drop *davon* because it's clear what you are referring to

> Du kannst jetzt nicht abspringen!

In this case, there is no doubt about the context (i. e. that it's about the plan).

On a note, you may also say "Wir hatten uns auf einen Plan geeinigt" to emphasize the agreement between you two (you didn't *just have some plan*, you had an *agreement*). So the second sentence gains more force - the other guy *agreed* to it and now wants to *bail out*!

Comment: *kneifen* is another verb that can be used nicely in colloquial sentences.

Comment: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kneifen) on *kneifen*: "salopp, abwertend sich einer Verpflichtung feige entziehen, sich vor etw. drücken"

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage: Does your comment imply that the draw back has no social obligation that get's "kicked"? I see such which means I avoid the social obligations I agreed upon agreeing to take part in case I "springe ab".

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Certainly, *abspringen* is not nice in the given context. I still feel it's a bit more neutral than *kneifen*. If you *spring ab*, you just violate your social obligation. In case of *kneifen*, you not just violate your social obligation, a hint at cowardice also enters the picture (even more so in the case of *Schwanz einziehen*). *Kneifen* is a bit more provocative.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solutions mentioned in other answers, here are some more feasible phrases:

> Ich und meine Freunde hatten Pläne wegzufahren. Ein paar haben aber kurz vorher einen Rückzieher gemacht.
>
> ... Ein paar haben sich kurz vorher verdünnisiert.
>
> ... Ein paar waren Wackelkandidaten und haben dann auch abgeagt.
>
> ... Ein paar haben kurz vorher noch abgesagt.
>
> ... Ein paar haben sich kurz vorher aus dem Staub gemacht.
>
> ... Ein paar haben kurz vorher kalte Füße bekommen.

Comment: das "s" hat auch abgeagt :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your translation fits.

To emphasize the "at last second", I would change this:

> Ich und meine Freunde hatten Pläne auszugehen. Ein paar von ihnen sind *kurz* davor abgesprungen.
>
> Wir hatten einen Plan. Du kannst jetzt nicht *[ ]* abspringen!

Because "von etwas abspringen" in the meaning of "skipping your involvment of doing something together" is not limited to the last possible moment, only to "if or if not".

So you would need to stress that "last moment".

What might be used mostly in moments close to the time of doing:

> den Schwanz einziehen

That comes with the meaning that the person that "[den Schwanz einzieht](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=kern&q=den%20schwanz%20einziehen&from=&h=1)"<sup>(no word entry, just examples that show the meaning literally)</sup>, "sich nicht traut/ kneift / keinen Mut hat/ feige ist/ die Konsequenzen nicht tragen will" ~ roughly does not have the courage. Proper word choice depends on context.

In your examples I would say "kneifen" fits best.

Comment: Schwanz einziehen does not imply at the last second, either.

Comment: @infinitezero: thinking about your comment: true, no causal indication, more correlation. I see the causal indication that I realize my consequences and tell my draw back in last possible moment (regarding what) to get not convinced again. So for the information receiver there is no choice left than to do the action without me.